# Geometry package unexpected interaction with global twoside option and baselinestretch

Tags: margins, geometry, incompatibility, double-sided

[image]

The gif animation is obtained with the following tex code (by commenting out and restoring the corresponding parts of the preamble) and demonstrates that if `twoside` option is supplied as a global one (instead of a package option) then the lengths of `marginparwidth` and `bottom` change.

I am only interested in the latter one because this together with the `baselinestretch` change leads to a badbox error (Underfull \vbox).

Do you have any explanation for this phenomenon or an idea to fix it? I am preparing a thesis template for our university and being able to supply `twoside`, `oneside` as a global option has its benefits (especially in a thesis document with a separate template file), otherwise the user needs to locate where the `geometry` package is loaded and modify the template file.

```
% \documentclass[12pt, a5paper]{report}
% \usepackage[margin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm, heightrounded, showframe]{geometry}
% \newcommand{\chapterheader}{package: empty}

% \documentclass[12pt, a5paper]{report}
% \usepackage[margin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm, heightrounded, showframe, asymmetric]{geometry}
% \newcommand{\chapterheader}{package: asymmetric}

% \documentclass[12pt, a5paper]{report}
% \usepackage[margin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm, heightrounded, showframe, twoside]{geometry}
% \newcommand{\chapterheader}{package: twoside}

% \documentclass[12pt, a5paper, oneside]{report}
% \usepackage[margin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm, heightrounded, showframe]{geometry}
% \newcommand{\chapterheader}{global: oneside}

% \documentclass[12pt, a5paper, asymmetric]{report}
% \usepackage[margin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm, heightrounded, showframe]{geometry}
% \newcommand{\chapterheader}{global: asymmetric}

\documentclass[12pt, a5paper, twoside]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, bindingoffset=1cm, heightrounded, showframe]{geometry}
\newcommand{\chapterheader}{global: twoside}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\chapter{\chapterheader{}}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```